# Best Pose Detection model for Django web-project with video upload

Tags: machine-learning, django

I am working on a Django project where a user can upload a video of a single person moving, and then run Pose Detection on the video such as MediaPipe, MoveNet or some other ML-model, and show the video with pose landmarks drawn on top of the video.

Can you give me some recommendations of which ML-model to choose to achieve this?